# Codeigniter Active Record - Prevent SQL Injection Attack

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
 $InsertDB= $this->db->insert_string('registerInsert',$registerData);
```

This is one of the codes  for insert. I have read the documentation of of "Active Record" and i still have some question about "SQL Injection Attack"

> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html
>   (Link of Documentation)

Based, on my insert codes , does it counted as "Active Record" and will it help to prevent SQL injection attack?

Comment: this is a simple Querybuilder operation - so yes it will prevent you from sql injection - Active Record on the other hand is a Design pattern with the purpose to save data to a RDBMS - so i don't really understand what you mean with _does it count_ - i don't think it matters...

Comment: @sintakonte, So when users enter  ( / . ' " ) it will count as "string" ? Or it will affect our sql query ?

Comment: the only way to know is to look under the hood, if it does prepared statements under it, then yes it may help you prevent sql injections

Comment: yes it does xaxacodess - CI is a proven framework for many years now - it is pretty robust - the only thing i dont understand is - why `insert_string` instead of `insert` ? `insert_string` returns the statement - and insert executes it